# Duda procedimiento unión de dos listas

Tags: c++, lista

tengo una duda con un ejercicio de listas, este es el enunciado:

> Desarollar    el  procedimiento     `void dll_union(dll_t<int>&   A,  dll_t<int>& B,  dll_t<int>& C)` que realiza la  unión   (tipo   conjunto)   de  dos listas  no  ordenadas   A   y   B   con elementos   no  repetidos,  y   devuelve    el  resultado   en  la  lista   C.  Para    ello, puede usarse  la  funcionalidad   desarrollada    en  el  apartado    (c).    Por ejemplo,    si  A={2,1,4,3} y   B={1,5,3,6},    el  resultado   sería   C={2,4,1,5,3,6}.

Aquí está la clase donde desarrollo el código:

```
#pragma once

#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

#include "dll_node_t.hpp"

using namespace std;

namespace AED {

    template <class T>
    class dll_t {
    private:
        dll_node_t<T>* head_;
        dll_node_t<T>* tail_;

        int sz_;

    public:
        dll_t(void);
        dll_t(const dll_t& L);
        virtual ~dll_t(void); 

        void insert_tail(dll_node_t<T>*);
        void insert_head(dll_node_t<T>*);

        dll_node_t<T>* extract_tail(void);
        dll_node_t<T>* extract_head(void);

        dll_node_t<T>* get_tail(void);
        dll_node_t<T>* get_head(void);

        bool empty(void) const ;
        int get_nz (void) const{}

        void unlink(dll_node_t<T>*);
        dll_node_t<int>* find (const int v);
        void dll_union (dll_t<int>& A, dll_t<int>& B, dll_t<int>& C);
        int get_size(void) const; // esto: contar los nonzeros



        void invert(void);




        ostream& write(ostream& os) const;
    };

    void dll_union (dll_t<int>& A, dll_t<int>& B, dll_t<int>& C){ // ESTE PROCEMIENTO LO HICE YO
        dll_node_t<int>* aux1 = A.get_head();
        dll_node_t<int>* aux2 = B.get_head();

        while (aux2 != NULL || aux1 != NULL){
            if (B.find((aux1->get_data()))){
                C.insert_tail(aux1);
            }



            if((aux1->get_data()) != (aux2->get_data())){
                C.insert_tail(aux1);
                C.insert_tail(aux2);
            }

            aux2=aux2->get_next();
            aux1=aux1->get_next(); 
        }
    }

    template<class T>

    dll_node_t<int>* dll_t<int> :: find(const int v){ // ESTE PROCEDIMIENTO LO HICE YO, SOSPECHO QUE MI PLANTEAMIENTO ESTÁ MAL o algo

        assert(!empty());

        dll_node_t <int>* aux = get_head();
        dll_node_t <int>* encontrado = NULL;

        while(aux !=NULL){
            if ((aux -> get_data())== v){
                encontrado= aux;
            }
            aux = aux-> get_next();
        }

        return encontrado;
    }


    template<class T>

    void dll_t<T> :: invert(void){ // ESTE PROCEDIMIENTO LO HICE YO

        assert(!empty());

        dll_node_t<T>* aux = get_tail();

        while (aux != NULL){
            extract_tail(aux);
            aux = aux -> get_prev();
        }

        while (aux !=NULL){
            insert_tail(aux);
            aux=aux->get_next();
        }
    }



template <class T>
    dll_t<T>::dll_t(void) :
    head_(NULL),
    tail_(NULL),
    sz_(0) {
    }

    template <class T>
    dll_t<T>::dll_t(const dll_t& L) :
    head_(NULL),
    tail_(NULL),
    sz_(0) {

       dll_node_t<T>* aux = L.head_;

        while (aux != NULL) {
            insert_tail(new dll_node_t<T>(aux->get_data()));
            aux = aux->get_next();
        }
    }

    template <class T>
    dll_t<T>::~dll_t(void) {

        dll_node_t<T>* aux = NULL;

        while (head_ != NULL) {
            aux = head_;
            head_ = head_->get_next();
            delete aux;
            aux = NULL;
        }
        sz_ = 0;
        head_ = NULL;
        tail_ = NULL;
    }
```

Al compilar, me salen unos errores que no entiendo, como estos:

```
 80 22      [Error] prototype for 'AED::dll_node_t<int>* AED::dll_t<int>::find(int)' does not match any in class 'AED::dll_t<int>'      

39  26      [Error] candidate is: AED::dll_node_t<int>* AED::dll_t<T>::find(int) [with T = int]
```

Sospecho que también tengo mal el planteamiento de dll_union,funcionar funciona, pero no arroja los resultados que yo quiero, me  basé en este noción de la unión de conjuntos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se agradece cualquier ayuda, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template <class T>
class dll_t {
```

`dll_t` es una plantilla... luego sus funciones deberían usar el tipo `T` en vez de `int`:

```
dll_node_t<int>* find (const int v);
//         ^^^               ^^^
//         MAL               MAL
void dll_union (dll_t<int>& A, dll_t<int>& B, dll_t<int>& C);
//                    ^^^            ^^^            ^^^
//                    MAL            MAL            MAL
```

Deberían lucir así:

```
dll_node_t<T>* find (const T v);
void dll_union (dll_t<T>& A, dll_t<T>& B, dll_t<T>& C);
```

Y lo mismo para las implementaciones:

```
template<class T>
dll_node_t<T>* dll_t<T>::find(const T v){

    assert(!empty());

    dll_node_t <T>* aux = get_head();
    dll_node_t <T>* encontrado = NULL;

    while(aux !=NULL){
        if ((aux -> get_data())== v){
            encontrado= aux;
        }
        aux = aux-> get_next();
    }

    return encontrado;
}
```

Con estos cambios entiendo que ya deberia compilarte.

En el caso de la función `invert`, ten en cuenta que en C, si a una función que no recibe parámetros no se le indica el `void` entiende que puede recibir cualquier cosa... mientras que C++ `void` se da por supuesto:

```
template<class T>
void dll_t<T> :: invert(void){ 
//                      ^^^^
//                      no es necesario en absoluto
```

Comment: Qué te parece el planteamiento de mi ejercicio?